# reshape batch matrices (3d array, each matrix is an image) to 2d (a grid of images)

Tags: numpy, numpy-einsum

Let's say we have a 3d array `A.shape = (100, 5, 5)`, each small matrix `(5,5)` is an image, now I want to reshape this 3d array into a square grid of images `B.shape=(50,50)`, so that the images are laid out as 10*10 grid.

I could do this with `np.stack` kind of tools, but I wonder if it's possible to do this using `np.einsum`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two simple solutions. Yours and its "transpose":

Example:

```
>>> ABCD.shape
(4, 41, 27)
>>> AC_BD = np.einsum('jik', ABCD.reshape(2, 82, 27)).reshape(82, 54)
>>> AB_CD = np.einsum('ikjl', ABCD.reshape(2, 2, 41, 27)).reshape(82, 54)
>>> Image.fromarray(AC_BD).show()
>>> Image.fromarray(AB_CD).show()
```

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I think I've just figured how

```
A = np.einsum('ijk->jik', A.reshape(10,50,5)).reshape(50,50); 
pl.imshow(A); 
pl.show()
```

Comment: Simpler: `A.reshape(10, 10, 5, 5).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(50, 50)` or `np.einsum('ikjl', A.reshape(10, 10, 5, 5)).reshape(50, 50)`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, the second is more interesting, what do you mean by `einsum('ikjl',...)`?

Comment: 'ikjl' is shorthand for 'ikjl->ijkl', i.e. the target in alphabetic order. Btw. after your edit this is no longer equivalent to your result. The arrangements of images are transposed.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, understood, I'd like to accept your solution, thanks